# What does role="button" mean?

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus, jquery-events

I found that in Google+ Project's page that buttons are all made from divs like:

```
<div role="button"></div>
```

I'd  like to know, is this just for semantic purposes, or does it influence the style or event handling of the `<div>`?

I tried to simulate a button "click" with the jQuery `click` event, but it didn't work.

Comment: +1 for pointing out it will not respond to jQuery click. Thank you

Comment: superset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-role-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It tells accessibility (and other) software what the purpose of the `div` is. More here in the [draft `role` attribute specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/role-attribute/).

Yes, it's just semantic. Sending a `click` event to the button *should* work.

---

An earlier version of this answer (back in 2011) said:

> ...but jQuery's `click` function doesn't do that; it triggers only the event handlers that have been hooked up to the element *with jQuery*, not handlers hooked up in other ways.

...and provided the sample code and output below.

I cannot replicate the output now (two years later). Even if I go back to earlier versions of jQuery, they all trigger jQuery handlers, DOM0 handlers, and DOM2 handlers. The order isn't necessarily the same between a real click and jQuery's `click` function. I've tried jQuery versions 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6, and more recent releases such as 1.7.1, 1.8.3, 1.9.1, and 1.11.3 (the current 1.x release as of this writing). I can only conclude that it was a *browser* thing, and I don't know what browser I was using. (Right now I'm using Chrome 26 and Firefox 20 to test.)

Here's a test which shows that indeed, jQuery handlers, DOM0 handlers, and DOM2 handlers are all (as of this writing!) triggered by jQuery's `click`:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var div;

  $("<p>").text("jQuery v" + $.fn.jquery).appendTo(document.body);

  // Hook up a handler *not* using jQuery, in both the DOM0 and DOM2 ways
  div = document.getElementById("theDiv");
  div.onclick = dom0Handler;
  if (div.addEventListener) {
    div.addEventListener('click', dom2Handler, false);
  } else if (div.attachEvent) {
    div.attachEvent('onclick', dom2Handler);
  }

  // Hook up a handler using jQuery
  $("#theDiv").click(jqueryHandler);

  // Trigger the click when our button is clicked
  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    display("Triggering <code>click</code>:");
    $("#theDiv").click();
  });

  function dom0Handler() {
    display("DOM0 handler triggered");
  }

  function dom2Handler() {
    display("DOM2 handler triggered");
  }

  function jqueryHandler() {
    display("jQuery handler triggered");
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theDiv">Try clicking this div directly, and using the button to send a click via jQuery's <code>click</code> function.</div>
<input type='button' id='theButton' value='Click Me'>
```

Comment: So how could I simulate click on that button?

Comment: @wong2: I'd post that question separately, it's different from the question about the `role` attribute. (I think you'd probably use [`createEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-DocumentEvent-createEvent) and [`dispatchEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent), but I'm pretty sure there are some browser compatibility issues there. I haven't done any simulated event firing, but my impression is that it's a cross-browser issue.)

Comment: Thanks. But why can't I simulate click the button in Google+ with JQuery click() ?

Comment: @wong2: Almost certainly because Google+ uses DOM2 style handlers (see the details above). Certainly that's what Google's Closure library uses, so it's a pretty safe bet.

Comment: I tried the document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); method, but not working in Google+'s page, only in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/apixez

Comment: @wong2: I expect there's a way, I really do think you should post it as its own question. I see you sort of did previously, but people got all caught up in the specifics of the button, the `$` function which they were sure was jQuery, etc., etc. Suggest a question that just cuts to the core: How do you simulate a click on a `div`, reliably, so that event handlers hooked with `addEventListener` and such are fired? **Not** using jQuery, because you're trying to do this on a page where jQuery isn't being used and you can't / don't want to introduce it.

Comment: It seems it's a little outdated and now it does trigger DOM2 in both cases.

Comment: @JakubKania: Thanks, good to know. I wonder if it was a browser thing, because I just tried it with various jQuery releases (using Chrome 26) dating back all the way to 2011 (the date of the answer), and using jQuery's `click` seems to fire DOM2 in all of them (the order varies a bit by release).

Answer (score 24):

It's just semantics.

It is recommended that you use native HTML buttons using `<button>` tag. However, if you are having custom controls using `<a>` or `<div>` tags, the following information on the `role='button'` is highly recommended.

1. **Trigger a Response**

If you are building custom controls, they should work just like a button. If you click the element, it should trigger a response. For example, This response isn't changing the text of the button i.e. custom control. If it is, then it is not a button.

2. **Keyboard focus**

These custom controls acting as buttons should be focusable by tabbing through a keyboard **and** also should be focusable programmatically for screen-readers, so you need to add `tabindex="0"`.

3. **Operability**

The custom control should implement [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) as well as [`onkeydown` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event).

Buttons (and links) can be activated through <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Hence, if you are adding the role to a custom control, you need to handle these events yourself. Else, the semantic loses its meaning. A screen-reader user will expect to activate the button using <kbd>Space</kbd>, but cannot.

The standard syntax for a custom control with the `role='button'` is

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0" onClick="click_handler()" onkeydown="keyhandler_for_space_and_enter()">
```

The `tabindex="0"` and `onkeydown` are not necessary if you are using `<a>` tag, but is required if you are using a non-focusable tag like `<span>` or `<div>` to manually allow focus.

Another useful tip is if you are still resorting to build custom button, it is much better to use `<a>` tag since you can avoid `onclick` handlers.

Comment: A good answer, with some useful details, but 'just semantics' might imply that it is not really important at all. Thousands of sites that are built with little more than div and span (because the devs didn't know, or didn't care about semantics) will now need the missing semantics to be added (e.g. with the role attribute) if there is any hope for them to be WCAG compliant.

Answer (score 6):

The `role` attribute is used by accessibility software to know what the `div` does. For more information, see [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-role/).