# bootstrap 3 accordion collapse does not work on iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

These "accordion submenus" work in chrome and firefox, but not on an iphone.

I have built a site which includes an "offcanvas" navigation menu on smaller screens.  The user clicks "the hot dog button", and the navigation menu slides onto the screen from the left... that works great so far.

Some of the navigation elements contain submenus. For those, I used bootstrap's accordion markup.  The user clicks an arrow, and the "submenu" expands.

[image]

**The Problem**

I develop using chrome on linux.  This mechanism works *perfectly* in chrome, firefox, and every browser I can get my hands on, as well as on my personal android phone.  It also works on [responsinator.com](http://www.responsinator.com/).  However, since I don't have Safari, nor an iPhone, I have not been able to test this functionality directly on an iphone.  I am working on getting an iPhone emulator...

Until then, some other people have looked at this on an iPhone, and I am told the "submenus" do not work at all.  When the user clicks the arrow, nothing happens...

Here is an excerpt of a "menu item" containing a "sub-menu": please note I am using the 'data-toggle' and 'data-target' attributes:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- The "Trigger" -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href="view.php?cms_nav_id=1" name="about">
                About</a>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
                <i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right mobile-nav-icon"></i>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <!-- Populated submenus: -->
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <a href="view.php?cms_nav_id=7" name="ohioimprovementprocess">Ohio Improvement Process</a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <a href="view.php?cms_nav_id=8" name="org/orgbeliefs">Organization Beliefs</a>  
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.panel -->
```

I really don't know what to try next: Similar questions have ended with "a css conflict" or iphone problems regarding `.click()`, but I am not using that: I am using `data-toggle/data-target`.  I am considering abandoning the 'data-target' markup in favor of manually invoking an `on('click', ... )` event, but I would rather not...

By the way, I call this at the bottom of my page if that's relevant:

```
<script src="/assets/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Which is 'bootstrap.js v3.0.0' .

Does anyone have any other clues? Any recent direct experience with an issue like this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the <a> tag? I want users to click anywhere on the `panel-heading`.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

So I think I figured this out: my original markup relied solely on the data-target element, but that is apparently not enough.  Safari (on iPhone) seems to also need the href attribute (which really should be there on an `<a>` anyway. So this works:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" href="#collapse1">
    <i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right mobile-nav-icon"></i>
</a>
```

But this does not:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
    <i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right mobile-nav-icon"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Actually related to tabs rather than menus, but this was the exact problem I was having with an IOS device. Nice one for working it out and thanks!

Comment: You should probably accept this as the correct answer. Thanks for solving this and post it out!

Comment: safari is the most nonstandard unsupported...hrg

Comment: Alternatively, I found that setting `style="cursor: pointer;"` to the element also works. Useful if you're not using an anchor tag!

Comment: To avoid jumping around when clicking on it, add `onclick="return false;"` to the `<a>` element.

Comment: I can't believe that the style="cursor: pointer;" solution is the only one that works for me. WTF! :D.
Thx @Loris

Answer (score 29):

For me, collapse would work on desktop and iphone, but some of my collapses were not working on ipads.  It turned out that perfect solution for me was given by @Loris in @Ryan's answer, to add the pointer style to any collapsable trigger (e.g., a div acting as a button).  I generalized this to the following CSS:

```
[data-toggle~="collapse"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You just saved a dude's life. Thank you.

Comment: Haha my pleasure. That gave my users trouble for a while. I had to borrow a friend's pad.

Comment: This worked a treat for bootstrap 4 accordion. I haven't used a button inside the card-header and just had the data-toggle on the div.

Comment: Dude! Your solution was super simple and saved a few hours of coding/finding for a solution. This should be marked as best answer. Thank you.

Comment: Agreed. Ryan's answer didn't work for me on the latest iPads, but this works fine on iPads and iPhones and is trivial to implement.

Answer (score 7):

looking at this, I had the same problem, however, when you add a href="#collapse1", it jumps you to the top of the page. I fixed this by wrapping the element in a button and removed the css for buttons. So, your code would be:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
<i class="pull-right icon-chevron-right mobile-nav-icon"></i>
</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to use a `DIV` with `data-toggle="collapse"`, but it wasn't working in iOS Chrome. Worked in regular Chrome on my computer. Changing the `DIV` to a `<button>` and removing all the default button styling did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it doesn't require adding an href, which causes the screen to jump around when a user opens/closes a panel.

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this by simply adding this attribute to the div that triggers the dropdown.

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me :

```
$('.divClassName').on('click touchstart', function () {
     $($(this).data('target')).collapse('toggle');
});
```

Comment: The touchstart save my day
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To make this work for any element type, such as a `div`, you can use the following jQuery method (tested ios 8):

```
<div class="collapse-header" data-target="#collapse_0">
    Click this element...
</div>
<div id="collapse_0">
    ...to collapse this element.
</div>

<script>
    $('.collapse-header').on('click', function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).collapse('toggle');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

for further reference:

I did this in my application:

```
a[data-toggle="collapse"]{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

And it fixed the problem.

In the MDN documentation says this:

"Safari Mobile 7.0+ (and likely earlier versions too) suffers from a bug where click events aren't fired on elements that aren't typically interactive (e.g. ) and which also don't have event listeners directly attached to the elements themselves (i.e. event delegation is being used). See this live example for a demonstration. See also Safari's docs on making elements clickable and the definition of 'clickable element'"

References:

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16213
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the animation will cause some problems in IOS devices. Disable it and it will work. That was the case for me.

```
[isAnimated]="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

2024 and Bootstrap version I am using is https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css and this problem for iphone still exist. For the programmers experiencing this until today. This is the solution I found.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Toggle the accordion
  $('.accordion-button').on('click', function() {
    var accordionContent = $(this).closest('.accordion-item').find('.accordion-collapse');
    accordionContent.slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

I almost gave up using bootstrap accordion and wanted to use the normal accordion with jquery. When miracle happens :) The jquery above works fro my bootstrap accordion. Hope this post can help!

Comment: here is the accordion <div class="card mb-3 custom-margin" id="uniqueAccordionDesign">
    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-item">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne" >
          </button>
        <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
         <div class="accordion-body">