# Bootstrap accordian not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm working on a project and I've run into the issue where the accordion function is not working on iOS. The site is live at [FanStatsApp.com](http://www.fanstatsapp.com) for you to try it out. It works for my roommates Android, but not on my iPhone's Safari or Chrome.

Here's my html.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#gamesplayed" class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge">5</span>
        See all games
        <div id="gamesplayed" class="collapse out">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[This is the closest thing I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866172/bootstrap-3-accordion-collapse-does-not-work-on-iphone), but it forces you to use <a>, and I really would not like to do that.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I did not. This was for a school project, so once the project was over I stopped attempting to figure it out.

Comment: "so once the project was over I stopped"--that's the spirit. You won't need to know how to do things once you leave school.

Comment: Sorry man. It was more of a side project that I could use as a project. When the project was done I graduated and kind of moved away from the project.