# Content not showing on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website it all works apart from the page below when used on a mobile device.
The accordion is supposed to work to show the menu items when that that menu section is active, but on mobile devices the content does not show up when the accordion is active?

http://valleyinn.ie/menus/menus.html

The html

```
<H1> A La Carte Menu </H1>
    <div class="wrapper"> 
    <ul class="accordion">
        <li class="nav-dropdown">
            <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="menu 1" />
            <label for="menu 1">
                Starters
            </label>
            <div>
                <h2>Starters</h2>
                <p>Prawn cocktail : Clogherhead prawns coated in Marie Rose sauce served with salad</p>
                <p>Garlic Bread: Garlic bread coated with mozarella cheese</p>
                <p>Bruchetta: Garlic toastie with tomato, basil and melted mozzarella</p>
                <p>Deep Fried Brie: Breaded parcels of Brie deep fried and served with redcurrant jelly</p>
                <p> Garlic Mushrooms: Deep fried breaded mushrooms with garlic mayonnaise</p>
                <P>Fan of Melon: Fan of honeydew melon served with Raspberry Coulis</P>
                <p>Caesar Salad: Crispy cos tossed with bacon, croutons & creamy caesar dressing with parmesan shavings</>
                <p>Soup of the Day
                <p>Chicken Wings: Marinated chicken wings served with sweet chilli dip & side salad</p>
                <p>Egg Mayonnaise</p>
                <P>Tiger Prawns: Served with honey mustard dressing & garlic bread</P>
            </div>
        </li>
```

and the css

```
div#title {
    text-align:center;
}
body div.wrapper {
    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    margin: 25px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
 }   
ul.accordion {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.accordion li input {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
ul.accordion label {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
    color:  #F9C921;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 42px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
ul.accordion label:hover {
    background-color: #F9C921;
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
ul.accordion li input ~ div {
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .05 );
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
ul.accordion li input ~ div p {
    font-size: .9em;
    margin: 16px 24px;  
}
h1 {
    clear:both;
}
ul.accordion li input:checked ~ div {
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
ul.accordion li input:checked ~ div > ul {
    display: block; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

any possible fixes or workarounds I cant think of where to start apart from making a mobile device specific page which I haven't done before

solved by changing code to avoid problem.

Comment: It's not working on any mobile browser I tried like chrome and safari, im trying all the fixes you suggested now thanks for the suggestions I shall tell you if it works or not

Comment: Just looking over your site again - I would have used tables in those expanding tabs so you can have title of the dish, description, and maybe a price?

Comment: decided to just use a bit of javascript and not have the drop downs for ios made things a lot easier I think

Answer (score 1):

In summary, different browsers parse code differently. And some are better in automatically "fixing" HTML errors. Check that the browser you are using the mobile device is updated. Then check if it supports that method.

In your code: 
You are missing a closing `</p>` as it shows only as `</>`, and two are uppercase `</P>` so change them to lowercase `</p>`, and `soup of the day` is missing a closing `</p>`. Also change the ID name from `menu 1` to `menu_1`.

Comment: changed the code around no change, browsers are all up to date but how would I check if its supported?

Comment: try: changing `<H1>` to `<h1>` and same for the closing `</H1>`. Also, you open to `<div>`'s but not closing them anywhere?

Comment: probably closed at end of code there is a lot of repetitive code if you look at the site so the divs close to end the group of accordions. The H shouldnt matter its the code inside the <p> that does not show

Comment: is the `<ul>` tag is closing anywhere?

Comment: Yeah this is what each section ends with        </div>
                                


      </li>
                        
      </ul>
    </div>

Comment: OK, I just accessed the URL from my Nexus 5 using Google's Chrome and the content shows just fine. Not sure what is the issue you are having

Comment: It happens in IOS and HTC as far as I know, but thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Will this solution help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866172/bootstrap-3-accordion-collapse-does-not-work-on-iphone

Comment: It works on any device through chrome device emulator, but I cant get it on any phones I have here, I might just include A link with if content not available press here and have a plain page with just text. Thanks again for your help

Comment: It sounds like it should but the only way I can think of implementing it is by adding href = "menu_1" to the label or input bits and neither works