# Bootstrap 3 accordion chevron issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've done the same thing that "WeaverSnap" said in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236717/how-to-make-bootstrap-accordion-collapse-when-clicking-div).

My accordion is just like the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weaversnap/7FqsX/1/) he posted.

The problem is, the chevron icons start in the wrong state, but fix themselfs after one of the panels get toggled.

It's a minor issue but i think it can be fixed.

Here is the CSS he provided: (I changed "FontAwesome" to "Glyphicons Halflings" BTW)

```
/* CSS Method for adding Font Awesome Chevron Icons */
 .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    content:"\f077";
    float: right;
    color: inherit;
}
.panel-heading.collapsed .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content:"\f078";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...if you're not adverse to it, you could just add the class `.collapsed` to each of the `.panel-heading` elements. So they would each look like something this:

```
<div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
    <!-- Child elements -->
</div>
```

This class dictates the facing of the chevron. You don't have to do this in the HTML directly; you could do it programmatically with jQuery when the page loads, since you've already got that loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel-heading").addClass("collapsed");
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FqsX/78/) that demonstrates this quick fix.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It worked like a charm, also fixed another issue I was having, thank you very much!

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks.
Though, it's a really inelegant solution, since - to have icons consistent with state on load - we have to use both **two** classes: add "collapsed" panel heading and not add "in" to panel body to have a closed panel, or not add "collapsed" to panel heading and add "in" to panel body to have an opened panel... Working with Angular, I'd have to write a directive for this... Any solution more fit for angular, anybody?

Comment: @MarcoS Hey, sorry that my answer here wasn't applicable enough to your situation - unfortunately, posting a comment might not give you enough visibility to get you the best solution. I'd suggest posting a new question, and linking back to this answer in your explanation of what you've tried, and why it hasn't worked out for you.

Comment: It did work, I only mean it works at cost of code cleanliness... I don't think a new question is required: it should be the same 1:1... What is required is a "better" answer... :-)