# role="button" for <a href

Tags: html, css

Hi I would like to know how bootstrap can add role="button" to there a href link.

```
<a href="" role="button">
```

I can not see the role button anywhere in the css

I am trying to make my own version.

Comment: In addition to Jake's answer below, here's some info on what `role` does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/role-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly do you want the link/button to do?

If you are just looking at styling the link to look like a bootstrap button you can just add the button classes to it:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">A Link</a>
```

if you want it to function like a button (ie submit a form or something) then you will need javascript or jQuery would be better in order to do that:

```
    <a href="#" id="myButton">A Link</a>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myButton").click(function(){
            $("#myFormID").submit();
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Then just combine the two and the anchor link will appear and act like a button.

Comment: Thank you !  The "href" attribute is really important else nothing will happen when you hit the "Enter" key.  To use keyboard navigation with tabindex="0"...