# need to understand a css/php sentence

Tags: php, css

Can someone please break this line down for me.

```
<div class="container" class="<?php wpp_css('property::content', "property_content"); ?>" role="main">
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

```
<div
```

It's a div element

```
class="container"
```

with the CSS class `container`.

```
class="<?php wpp_css('property::content', "property_content"); ?>"
```

This is wrong! An element can have only one `class` attribute!
But it seems that you try to add custom CSS classes with the PHP function `wpp_css`.

```
role="main">
```

Your div has the attribute `role` with value `main`. [More info about roles here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/role-attribute-in-html).

### Corrected div:

```
<div class="container <?php wpp_css('property::content', "property_content"); ?>" role="main">
```

Comment: Yes, but it can only have one attribute `class=""` This is not correct: <div class="class1" class="class2"></div>

Comment: oyes i see i didn't say a word

Comment: I hope the edit looks good to you.. if not please rollback :)

Comment: looks fantastic, thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

wpp_css is a function,  first parameter is 'property::content' second parameter is "property_content"

i think it is used to pass the right content to the container

Answer (score 0):

You create a div with a dynamic class. The class is being generated ny a PHP function called wpp_css and the div's role is main

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your using "`WordPress Popular Posts`" plugin and the method wpp_css() is a method of this plugin to determining which CSS class should be applied to your container div.

It first checks that whether any value is set for the '`property::content`' property or not. If it is set then it returns that otherwise it returns '`property_content`'.

You also have two class attributes in your div. You should change them like this.

```
<div class="container <?php wpp_css('property::content', "property_content"); ?>" role="main">
```