# How does a TWEET composition textbox work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, cookies, twitter

The Twitter input box is much more than your average INPUT or textarea.  First off, it isn't an input or textarea at all.  They are instead using a well crafted DIV with a ["role" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-role-attribute-in-html). for the entire text; likely capturing keystokes as they occur.

If a user is logged in, they can compose a tweet.  If during that very cautious 140 character sprint, they accidentally click somewhere on the page, the browser GETs another page.

But when the user hits "back", the DIV then repopulates (after a second), with the users partially drafted tweet.

In terms of browser capability, how is this "saved form field" being accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing to achieve this, one could implement either:

1. [local-storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)
   This would just involve writing to the local storage upon each keystroke.  Upon loading the page, the JS populates the tweet composer with the session local storage.  See a live [example](http://html5demos.com/storage) of utilizing local storage.  This would be nice and slick, but a major limitation is that this is limited to HTML5  browsers.
2. AJAX callback
   Similar to the first method, but instead of writing to local-storage, the draft tweet is written to a web service.  Upon loading the page, a callback is made to retrieve the content; populating the tweet composer.
3. Cookie approach.
   Similar to the local-storage, but would write to cookie cache.  The benefit with this method might be more ubiquitous browser support.

I'd love for someone to explain the pro's/con's of each method along with some sample code.  Bonus if it's under 140 characters for each code sample :) (j/k).