# Why there are some unknown attributes in the <nav> tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new to web design, falling into javascript design with bootstrap, but every now and then, I CAN find some attributes in tags that seems not supported anywhere. I am really confused.

For example: the following code about "nav" tag

```
<nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas"     role="navigation">
  <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
<ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

why we can have "role" attribute here for "nav" tag? I have searched all the possible resources:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp   suggested  [Global Attributes in HTML.] and [Event Attributes in HTML.] are supported for "nav", however "role" is in neither of them.

**I am just wondering How can we add attributes that are not allowed seemingly at will?**

**Could someone please help explain How bootstrap javascript matching works that just by adding data-toggle and data-target, we can have certain active effects on certain target？**

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/usage

Comment: You didn't try searching, did you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-role-attribute-in-html

Comment: You seem to be asking several questions. The `role` attribute is an accessibility feature. See the links we've provided. Then, you can create your own HTML-compliant attributes by prefixing `data-` to just about anything.

Comment: Just as a note, w3schools is not the official documentation for web standards. They are also not always up to date. On the other hand, w3.org (with which w3schools has *no* affiliation) is the official spec website.

Comment: There is nothing fancy about the attributes in the tag. You are just using a horrendously unreliable site as a reference. Consider consulting the authoritative HTML references.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has jquery plugins that parse the page and use those data-xxxx attributes to instrument their elements with handlers. Although it is not always a good idea to create your own attributes (normally intellisense will balk unless you add the "data-" or "x-" prefix) there is nothing keeping you from doing it. It will mean nothing to the DOM but Javascript and jQuery can still use them as though they were valid attributes.