# Role attribute obsolete in form or nav tags

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, wai-aria

### Introduction

I know, the role attribute was introduced by W3C in [WAI-ARIA 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) and was then adapted in *HTML5*.

When HTML5 was new and many browser didn't implement the native elements [people advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-role-attribute-in-html) to back them up with the role attribute like `<nav role="nav">…</nav>`, but they also mentioned that this will become *unnecessary* soon.

But at the moment, there are different opinions:

---

### Bootstrap

A bootstrap member stated on [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13727) that the WAI-ARIA rules are "more important" then the current HTML5 specifications. Also, other third-party sites like [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.htm) or [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp) also recommend to add the attribute to grant full accessibility.

---

### W3C

On the other side, the W3C-Validator gives the following warning when you input the questionable form tag with a role attribute.

```
<form role="form"></form>
```

> Element form does not need a role attribute.

This would clearly speak for not including the role attribute.

---

### Finally

Has the time already come to neglect *backing up* the native HTML5 tags (and forms), or is it still necessary to guarantee a fully accesible website (e.g. for handicapped people/people with screen readers)? Is there a kind of "official statement" or a guideline (which is up-to-date)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker (validator) here. The short answer is that the [current authoritative requirement that’s relevant to the `<form role="form"></form>`](http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#rules-wd) case is this:

> Web developers should not set the ARIA `role` and `aria-*` attributes to
>   values that match the default implicit ARIA semantics defined in the
>   table.

…where “*the table*” means the table in the [Document conformance requirements for use of ARIA attributes in HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#docconformance) section of the [ARIA in HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/) spec, the latest version of which you can find here:

http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/

And the reason that spec is authoritative is because [the HTML spec itself formally references it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#wai-aria):

> Conformance checker requirements for checking use of ARIA `role` and
>   `aria-*` attributes on HTML elements are defined in *[ARIA in HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/)*.

The W3C checker therefore strictly follows the rules in *ARIA in HTML*. So, given the following:

- `<form role="form"></form>` is a case of setting a `role` value for the `form` element that matches the default implicit semantics of the `form` element, and;
- the relevant rule in the *ARIA in HTML* is that a `role` value *should not* be set to a value that matches the default implicit semantics of the element

…the checker therefore gives that *Element form does not need a role attribute* warning.

> Is there a kind of "official statement" or a guideline (which is
>   up-to-date)?

Yes, that’s exactly what the *[ARIA in HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/)* spec is.

Any source conflicting with *ARIA in HTML* spec rules is wrong or outdated and should be corrected.