# Does every div, section, main, and article need to have a role attribute

Tags: html, css, web, accessibility, wai-aria

Does every single div, section, main, and article need to have the role attribute for accessibility? Only asking because a colleague mentioned that, and now I feel like I have to redo a lot of markup. For instance, what if you're using a div for styling purposes?

Let's say I have HTML that looks like:

```
<div role="Heading" aria-labelledby="website-heading">
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Is role="Heading" necessary in this instance?

Comment: I would say: No.

Comment: question has already been answered:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-role-attribute-in-html

Comment: @DCR Good find. In the future, you can just click the flag link below the question, select should be closed, duplicate of, then paste that link right in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div role="Heading" aria-labelledby="website-heading">
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <hr>
</div>
```

The `heading` role is not only non-necessary but uncorrect.

This would mean that the inner `<h1>` has a parent heading with a `aria-level` which can't exist as `h1` is the first existing level within headings.

Answer (score -1):

No its not compulsory or a good practice to add role attribute to every div or section you have in a page. If you want to remember the roles of your different sections or div's then you can always use html comments