# Angular Material Schematics generated code

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am new to Angular and can't find anything which explains what the precise meaning of these lines of the code generated from the `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav`.

The following lines in particular are unclear to me:

```html
[attr.role]="isHandset ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
[mode]="(isHandset | async)!.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
[opened]="!(isHandset | async)!.matches">
```

More specifically, what are these properties (where can I see them?), I am also unclear as to what many of the words mean for example `matches` or the | character? Any explanation or reference to documentation would be helpful.

The full HTML of the generated command is here:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="isHandset ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset | async)!.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset | async)!.matches">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="(isHandset | async)!.matches">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>Application Title</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

And the corresponding .ts file:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'newnav',
  templateUrl: './newnav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newnav.component.css']
})
export class NewnavComponent {
  isHandset: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);
  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
}
```

Comment: if @Phil answer satisfies you, you should mark his answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breakpoint(Observer) according to this tutorial: https://alligator.io/angular/breakpoints-angular-cdk/

> The Angular CDK has a layout package with services that make it easy to detect viewport sizes and matches against media queries. This allows you full control over the UI and to adapt to different screen sizes.

So a breakpoint is the turning point when, for example, a resolution is not considered landscape-mode anymore, but portrait-mode. Or in the case of isHandset, when the resolution is small enough to be "officially" considered a handset/mobile-device.

The `Observable` in `isHandset: Observable<BreakpointState>` means the Angular CDK framework injects an RXJS stream rather than a static value. So you need to subscribe to the stream in order to get the last value and all subsequent updates.

`isHandset | async` means Angular's async-Pipe is being used. Async-pipe automatically subscribes to a stream, returns the value, triggers change detection and unsubscribes from a stream (it is important to unsubscribe to avoid memory leakage).

The `!.` in (isHandset | async)! is a not-null assertion, preventing from an error being thrown when accessing a property if isHandset has no value in the stream yet. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators

The ! in `!(isHandset | async)!.matches` flips the boolean-result of the matches-check

The `evaluation ? ifTrue : ifFalse` is the if-else-operator known to many programming languages. And [something] is Angular's way of putting data from the parent component to the child. So as result, the line `[mode]="(isHandset | async)!.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"` passes over a string-value as the `@Input`-configuration of the module, based on whether you are on the mobile or not.

These should be all the hard parts in the code. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Mind shedding some light on `[attr.role]="isHandset ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"` :)

Comment: Seems like that line might be generated incorrectly and thus be a bug.

Comment: @IngoBürk I ain't sure but could it be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664038/5695162)

Comment: Sorry, I meant it looks like a bug because isHandset is an observable and for the role attribute it's not being subscribed.

Comment: @IngoBürk I figured out rest of the things only had a doubt with that Thanx Mate :)

Comment: I would confirm what @IngoBürk said, this does look like a bug

Comment: BTW, I am kind of disappointed the Google team itself doesn't follow it's code guidelines and use $ at the end of Observable-variables

Comment: Indeed and the documentation sucks to the core :( BTW Mate great answer.

Comment: @Phil They're only human, too. I'm sure that if you send a PR, they'd merge it :)