# How come some people use "role" attribute instead of "type"?

Tags: html, button, element

I'm following along with a YouTube video & it's teaching me about buttons. The video uses the attribute `role`, but how come they use `role` instead of `type`?

```
<button type="button"></button>
<button role="button"></button>
```

Which one should I use and why? None of the HTML documentation I've looked up shows a role as an attribute for the button.

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403138/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-role-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 0):

> The role attribute describes the role of an element in programs that
> can make use of it, such as screen readers or magnifiers.
>
> The button role should be used for clickable elements that trigger a
> response when activated by the user. Adding role="button" will make an
> element appear as a button control to a screen reader. This role can
> be used in combination with the aria-pressed attribute to create
> toggle buttons.

Read more on this from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

Since you are already using a `button` element. It no longer needs `role="button"` attribute since it is itself a `button` and all the events are already available.

So it is not recommended to use `role="button"` on `button`.