# Jquery simulate a click on <div role = button>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to simulate a click on a button using jquery.

Regular Javascript MouseEvents (mousedown and mouseup) do work, but I want jquery.

I have the div in a jquery object: (just a reference)

it was defined like

```
var $button = $(document.getElementById("iframe")...);
```

`$button` -> `<div id="1" class="2" role = "button"><b>Action</b></div>`

I've tried with `$button.click()` and `$button.trigger('click')` but both don't work.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562407/what-does-role-button-mean), but provides no answer to this question.

Comment: Can you post more code?

    $('#foo').trigger('click');

should work...

Comment: Need more context on your javascript and HTML.

Comment: $('#foo').click() should also work

Comment: Now, I'm assuming that your $button was defined earlier as var $button = $('button'), correct? In that case you trigger a click just like you tried with the trigger, or simply $('button').click();

Comment: No it was not like this, it took a division of an existing HTML page, that performs an action outside of my script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
$button[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't fire events attached with dom2 methods, sorry. It only fires its own events. And accidentally click/submit dom0 events in some cases as a result of calling the `.click()/.submit()` method on native dom elements where they exist.

Comment: I think that's the sad answer