# Simulate click on GMail div button with JS

Tags: javascript, click, gmail, simulate

I want to simulate click on GMail COMPOSE button using JS without JQuery.

Here is button:

```
<div class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3" role="button" tabindex="0" gh="cm" 
style="-webkit-user-select: none;">COMPOSE</div>
```

Here is my js:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('T-I-KE')[0];
element.click();
```

Result:`undefined` in all browsers

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkscf.png

Already tried that:

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
event.initEvent("click",true,true);
var element=document.getElementsByClassName("T-I-KE")[0];
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Result:`true`. But nothing happens.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3KSH.png

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765093/4506790

Comment: don't working. Returns true. But nothing happens. Result image: http://i.imgur.com/pwVqukP.png

Comment: I have found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549234 and that works for me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After two days i am finally got an answer!

That button listens mouseDown and mouseUP events.
Working code:

```
var down = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
var up = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("T-I-KE")[0];
elem.dispatchEvent(down);
elem.dispatchEvent(up);
```

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer on how to monitor events -- it will save you a lot of head scratching :).

Comment: This works well for some buttons (like 'compose' or 'more') but has any effect on other buttons (like 'settings' in the right corner). After few hours of monitoring events I gave up. Anyone is able to click 'settings' programatically?

Answer (score -1):

The function `getElementsByClassName(classString)` will return the elements with the class of exactly the string that you pass to it. Try using [querySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp), like this

```
document.querySelector(".T-I-KE");
```

That will return the first element with the class `T-I-KE`. If you want ALL the elementes with that class, call the function `querySelectorAll` instead

Comment: I don't have issues with selecting a button. I can't simulate click on it.
Here is your example: http://i.imgur.com/riFnz1o.png
Result the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
function click(tagNode) {
    const down = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
        bubbles: true
    });
    const up = new MouseEvent('mouseup', {
        bubbles: true
    });
    tagNode.dispatchEvent(down);
    tagNode.dispatchEvent(up);
}
```